# Finding border pixels of a image with transparent surrounding (for collision detection)

Tags: java, android, sprite, collision-detection, transparent

I'm programming a game and I want to collide images with transparent borders (sprites) against a circle.

It's easy to know if the circle is overlapping the image by checking collision with the pixels which are not transparent.

The problem I have is to know the normal angle in order to make a bounce.

I would need a library (Java) or algorithm that given an image it would return an array with the pixels that are at the border of the image so i can find the slope between two points of the surface.

Is there any library/algorithm/code snippet i can learn from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

Create a mask from the original image where all transparent pixels are `0` and all non-transparent pixels are `1`

Then, perform a simple edge detection on your mask by subtracting each pixel `(x,y)`, which will be `0` or `1`, from pixel `(x+1,y+1)` and taking the absolute value.

This will give you a `1` for pixels on the edge of the image and a `0` everywhere else.

Note: this method is essentially equivalent to treating the image as a 2d function and calculating its gradient. The edges are *steep* parts of the intensity surface (which correspond to large gradient values). Here's some more information on [gradient-based edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection#Other_first-order_methods).

---

Here's an example image:

[image: Original Test Image]

First mask all the non-transparent pixels:

[image: Image Mask]

Then shift the image down and over one pixel and subtract it from itself.

This creates the image below. Now simply read out the matrix indices with value `1`.

That's your array of edge pixels.

[image: Edge Mask]

Note: if your images contain interior transparent pixels, this technique will also find interior edges, which may or may not be a problem for you...

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'v implemented over the time: (detectionStrength is best 10)

```
public static List<Pixel> getEdges(Image image, int detectionStrength) {

    boolean[][] opaque = new boolean[image.getWidth(null)][image
            .getHeight(null)];
    LinkedList<Pixel> edges = new LinkedList<Pixel>();
    int rgb;

    /*
     * convert to BufferedImage to get individual pixel colors
     */
    BufferedImage bufferedImage;
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage)
        bufferedImage = (BufferedImage) image;
    else {
        bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null),
                image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        bufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < opaque.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < opaque[i].length; j++) {
            rgb = bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
            opaque[i][j] = (rgb >> 24 & 0xFF) > detectionStrength; // transparency
        }
    }

    /*
     * If a pixel is opaque, but is surrounded, with at least one
     * transparent pixel, it is considered an edge.
     */
    for (int x = 0; x < opaque.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < opaque[x].length; y++) {
            if ((x == 0) || (x == opaque.length - 1) || (y == 0)
                    || (y == opaque[x].length - 1)) { // border pixel
                if (opaque[x][y]) // if opaque, it is automatically an edge,
                                    // no matter its surrounding...
                    edges.add(new Pixel(x, y, new Color(bufferedImage
                            .getRGB(x, y))));

            } else { // not a border pixel
                if (opaque[x][y]
                        && (!opaque[x - 1][y - 1] || !opaque[x][y - 1]
                                || !opaque[x + 1][y - 1]
                                || !opaque[x - 1][y] || !opaque[x + 1][y]
                                || !opaque[x - 1][y + 1]
                                || !opaque[x][y + 1] || !opaque[x + 1][y + 1]))
                    edges.add(new Pixel(x, y, new Color(bufferedImage
                            .getRGB(x, y))));
            }
        }
    }

    return edges;
}
```

And the Pixel class (just a very simple extension of `Point`) :

```
public class Pixel extends Point implements Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9053911985748552077L;

    public Color color;

    public Pixel(int x, int y, Color c) {
        super(x, y);
        color = c;
    }

    public Pixel(Pixel other) {
        super(other.x, other.y);
        color = other.color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color newColor) {
        color = newColor;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((color == null) ? 0 : color.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Pixel))
            return false;
        Pixel other = (Pixel) obj;
        if (color == null) {
            if (other.color != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!color.equals(other.color))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Object clone() {
        return new Pixel(x, y, color);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Pixel [color=" + color + ", x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }
}
```

The image created with the algorithm, will be:

[image: StackOverflow logo]

Comment: i got a negative array size exception.while running the code

Comment: Make sure your image is completed loading beforehand, by checking image width/height.